# Reorganize By Arrows

Tags: code-golf

Lets say I was writing something, and I accidentally wrote it in the wrong box:

```
+-------+--------+
| Verbs | Nouns  |
+-------+--------+
| Truck |        |
| eat   | Banana |
|       | Car    |
+-------+--------+
```

So I, being lazy, merely draw an arrow to the space it should be:

```
+-------+--------+
| Verbs | Nouns  |
+-------+--------+
|[Truck]--->     |
| eat   | Banana |
|       | Car    |
+-------+--------+
```

Your job is to make it look pretty - turn it into this:

```
+-------+--------+
| Verbs | Nouns  |
+-------+--------+
|       | Truck  |
| eat   | Banana |
|       | Car    |
+-------+--------+
```

### Rules

- Phrases or words are surrounded by brackets ([...])
- <s>Multiline entries are denoted as [...]</s> (multiline removed), newline, [...]--...-->. So the arrow always comes out of the **<s>bottom</s> right bracket**

For example:

```
+-----------+----------+
|   Verbs   |  Nouns   |
+-----------+----------+
|           |          |
|[is a noun]->         |
| eat       | Banana   |
|           | Car      |
+-----------+----------+
```

Turns into:

```
+-----------+----------+
|   Verbs   |  Nouns   |
+-----------+----------+
|           |          |
|           | is a noun|
| eat       | Banana   |
|           | Car      |
+-----------+----------+
```

- Boxes are bounded by pluses ("+"), and it should be assumed that arrows will not pass over a plus
- There will always be room at the end of an arrow for the word or phrase to fit
- Order matters - the word must appear where the arrow points to, though vertical alignment is not important
- Arrows can turn by 90 degrees at a time, but only between "/" and "\" (see below)

For example:

```
    +-----------+----------+
    |   Verbs   |  Nouns   |
    +-----------+----------+
    | [Truck]--\|          |
  /------------/|        <--\
  | | eat       | Banana   ||
  | |  /--\     | Car      ||
  | +--|--|-----+----------+|
  \----/  \-----------------/
```

### The Competition

Any input is acceptable (text file, STDIN, etc.)
any readable output is acceptable (text file, STDOUT, etc)

Here are some more examples:

This is code golf, so shortest code wins!

Some test cases:

```
   +--------+----------+-------------+
   | Colors |  Foods   |  Countries  |
   +--------+----------+-------------+
   | red    | pizza    | Switzerland |
 /-->     /---->       |             |
 | |[kale]/ | hot dogs | Brazil      |
 | |     <----------------------\    |
 | | orange |[yellow]\ | [green]/    |
 | +--------+--------|-+-------------+
 \-------------------/


/------------------------------------------\
|                                          |
|  +------------------+----------+-------+ |
|  | frog             |          |       | |
|  | forge            | dog      | eagle | |
|  | foundation       | diligent | ease  | |
|  |[Brother]--\      | down     | elf   | |
|  |           |      |[egg]--\  |[fort]---/
\---->         |      |       |  |       |  
   |           \-\    |       \----->    |  
   +-------------|----+----------+       |  
   |   Boy       \-->            |       |  
   |   Bull                      |       |  
   |   Browser                   |       |  
   +-----------------------------+-------+ 


             /--------------------------------------\
             |                     /---------------\|
/------------|---------------------/               ||
|            |               /---------------\     ||
|  +---------|-+-----------+-|------+--------|+    ||
\---->       | |  clarinet | \>     | [drums]/|    ||
   | [viola]\\--->         |        +---------+    ||
   |        \----->        |        |         |/---/|
   +-----------+ [violin]\ |        | [cello]--/    |
   |        <------------/ |        +---------+     |
   |           +-----------+      <----------\|     |
   |           |           |        |  [tuba]/|     |
   |           | [piano]\  |        |         |     |
   |        <-----------/  |        |         |     |
   |           +-----------+--------+         |     |
   |           |                    |[trumpet]------/
   | [flute]----->                  |         |      
   |           |     saxaphone      |         |      
   +-----------+--------------------+---------+
```

Comment: This is a nice challenge, it just seems bloody hard!

Comment: I guess you can also use `|` to make everything prettier.

Comment: In the last example, `[Clarinet]` isn't going anywhere, can we not assume that anything inside square brackets is going to move?

Comment: While attempting to write box identification, I've noted that it's possible for it to be ambiguous how many boxes there are if you have enough arrows crossing a boundary, for example, How many boxes are there in this layout http://pastebin.com/xyBjTAwK ? Can we have some guarantee that this won't occur, or an explanation of expected behaviour for the situation.

Comment: @VisualMelon You can assume that won't happen. There will never be a case where 2 pluses are in the next row/column and not be connected. Also, about the brackets, that was a flaw on my part. You can assume that anything in brackets moves.

Comment: What is the policy on trailing spaces/line breaks in the output?

Comment: All I ask is that it outputs a table that looks like the original table, except with the values moves. In other words, as long as it looks like a table (e.g. no random line breaks), I don't care about things I can't see (e.g. trailing spaces/line breaks)

Comment: Regarding *"Order matters"*, what do you expect for the second test case entry "Brother"? Can you qualify the requirements for positioning of moved items (my current implementation is working on the assumption that each box has multiple rows, each with a single item in it, because there is no guarantee that 3 multi line items won't be pointing to 3 consecutive rows; now I'm thinking that I can't treat each box as a single column?). Can you please also clarify what qualifies as an item (i.e. non-whitespace text with any of \-|>< omitted). Thanks

Comment: On the order, if the top of the item is put right where the arrow is pointing, then it should be in the right place. For example, "Brother" would go to the right of "Boy". You can assume that the arrow is pointing to the first row of the destination of a multirow item. On what qualifies an item - Anything surrounded by brackets (even ><|^ and whitespace) is considered part of the item. If there are brackets above it without an arrow coming out, then it is part of a multiline item.

Comment: I like this, but there's a couple of things putting me off answering. 1.There's supposed to be enough space, but it seems the order you do the moves matters. If you move KALE before YELLOW there's no problem, but if you move YELLOW before KALE you risk overwriting part of the arrow for KALE 2.multiline moves seem complicated. Also it's not clear where the line should go to. In [A   ][CELLO] the arrow leaves from the lower row, but if it is pasted into place with the lower row lined up with the arrow head it overwrites the top of the box. And if it's posted one line lower, it overwrites VIOLA

Comment: perhaps I should get rid of multiline?

Comment: To make it easier can we assume that if we put the word exactly where the arrow points (be it word starts there for arrow pointing right or word ends there for arrow pointing left), there'll be enough room in the box? When moving yellow, if you start the word right there, it'll override the box boundary.

Comment: @steveverrill: overwriting arrows isn't a problem I think, you just have to keep track of them separately, eg you can dup the input and write into the duplicate

Comment: I would be for @Claudiu proposition, I've all but given up trying to complete the task to the current spec, because there are too many things that aren't strictly defined, and I don't want to fill these comments up with dozens of questions.

Comment: Ok, multinine removed and "yellow" fixed, you can assume that words will fit on the line.

Comment: I think there's an ambiguous case. Say the input is [this](http://pastebin.com/qfY88qmU). You can't know whether there's a box in the middle ([choice 1](http://pastebin.com/SpLDsXgu) ) or whether there isn't ([choice 2](http://pastebin.com/4GerLegv) ). Can I just assume choice 2 would be a valid output?

Comment: @Claudiu both of those are correct. In the case of an ambiguity like that, you can just choose one of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Python, <s>700</s> <s>681</s> <s>676</s> 667 characters

Not fully golfed yet, but wanted to put up an answer.

```
import os
D=map(list,os.read(0,9999).split('\n'))
Z=Q=[-1,0,1,0,-1]
J=''.join
def T(y,x,d,_):c=D[y][x];D[y][x]=' ';d={'\\':3-d,'/':1-d}.get(c,d)%4;j=(y+Q[d],x+Q[d+1],d,c=='>');return c in'<>'and j or T(*j)
def F(y,x,d):
 if y<Y or x<L:
    if D[y][x]=='+':
     if J(D[y]).find('+',x+1)+1:F(y,x+1,1)
     if any((l[x:]+[''])[0]=='+'for l in D[y+1:]):F(y+1,x,2)
    else:D[y][x]='--||'[d];F(y+Q[d],x+Q[d+1],d)
i=0
for l in D:
 I=l.index
 if'+'in l:
    if Z:P,K,L,Z=i,I('+'),J(l).rfind('+'),0
    Y=i
 while'['in l:
    s,e=map(I,'[]');y,x,_,R=T(i,e+1,1,1);W=l[s+1:e]
    if R:D[y][x:x+e-s-1]=W
    else:D[y][x-e+s+2:x+1]=W
    l[s:e+1]=' '*(e-s+1)
 i+=1
F(P,K+1,1);F(P+1,K,2)
for l in D:print J(l)
```

**Strategy**:

I turn the input into a matrix. Then I scan it line by line, finding `[`s. For every `[`, I find the matching `]`, then I call the trace function `T` with the spot immediately to the right of the `]`. The trace function follows the line, replacing the path with `' '`s as it goes, and returns where the word should go. Then I erase the word in the old location and put the word in the new location.

Finally, I call `F`, which recursively reconstructs the boxes.

**Tests**:

```
reorg_test1... True
Input:
+-------+--------+
| Verbs | Nouns  |
+-------+--------+
|[Truck]--->     |
| eat   | Banana |
|       | Car    |
+-------+--------+


Output:
+-------+--------+
| Verbs | Nouns  |
+-------+--------+
|       |   Truck|
| eat   | Banana |
|       | Car    |
+-------+--------+



reorg_test2... True
Input:
+-----------+----------+
|   Verbs   |  Nouns   |
+-----------+----------+
|           |          |
|[is a noun]->         |
| eat       | Banana   |
|           | Car      |
+-----------+----------+


Output:
+-----------+----------+
|   Verbs   |  Nouns   |
+-----------+----------+
|           |          |
|           | is a noun|
| eat       | Banana   |
|           | Car      |
+-----------+----------+



reorg_test3... True
Input:
    +-----------+----------+
    |   Verbs   |  Nouns   |
    +-----------+----------+
    | [Truck]--\|          |
  /------------/|        <--\
  | | eat       | Banana   ||
  | |  /--\     | Car      ||
  | +--|--|-----+----------+|
  \----/  \-----------------/


Output:
    +-----------+----------+
    |   Verbs   |  Nouns   |
    +-----------+----------+
    |           |          |
    |           |   Truck  | 
    | eat       | Banana   | 
    |           | Car      | 
    +-----------+----------+ 




reorg_test4... True
Input:
   +--------+----------+-------------+
   | Colors |  Foods   |  Countries  |
   +--------+----------+-------------+
   | red    | pizza    | Switzerland |
 /-->     /---->       |             |
 | |[kale]/ | hot dogs | Brazil      |
 | |     <----------------------\    |
 | | orange |[yellow]\ | [green]/    |
 | +--------+--------|-+-------------+
 \-------------------/


Output:
   +--------+----------+-------------+
   | Colors |  Foods   |  Countries  |
   +--------+----------+-------------+
   | red    | pizza    | Switzerland |
   | yellow |   kale   |             |
   |        | hot dogs | Brazil      |
   |green   |          |             |
   | orange |          |             |
   +--------+----------+-------------+




reorg_test5... True
Input:
/------------------------------------------\
|                                          |
|  +------------------+----------+-------+ |
|  | frog             |          |       | |
|  | forge            | dog      | eagle | |
|  | foundation       | diligent | ease  | |
|  |[Brother]--\      | down     | elf   | |
|  |           |      |[egg]--\  |[fort]---/
\---->         |      |       |  |       |  
   |           \-\    |       \----->    |  
   +-------------|----+----------+       |  
   |   Boy       \-->            |       |  
   |   Bull                      |       |  
   |   Browser                   |       |  
   +-----------------------------+-------+ 


Output:


   +------------------+----------+-------+  
   | frog             |          |       |  
   | forge            | dog      | eagle |  
   | foundation       | diligent | ease  |  
   |                  | down     | elf   |  
   |                  |          |       |  
   |  fort            |          |       |  
   |                  |          |   egg |  
   +------------------+----------+       |  
   |   Boy           Brother     |       |  
   |   Bull                      |       |  
   |   Browser                   |       |  
   +-----------------------------+-------+ 



reorg_test6... True
Input:
             /--------------------------------------\
             |                     /---------------\|
/------------|---------------------/               ||
|            |               /---------------\     ||
|  +---------|-+-----------+-|------+--------|+    ||
\---->       | |  clarinet | \>     | [drums]/|    ||
   | [viola]\\--->         |        +---------+    ||
   |        \----->        |        |         |/---/|
   +-----------+ [violin]\ |        | [cello]--/    |
   |        <------------/ |        +---------+     |
   |           +-----------+      <----------\|     |
   |           |           |        |  [tuba]/|     |
   |           | [piano]\  |        |         |     |
   |        <-----------/  |        |         |     |
   |           +-----------+--------+         |     |
   |           |                    |[trumpet]------/
   | [flute]----->                  |         |      
   |           |     saxaphone      |         |      
   +-----------+--------------------+---------+ 


Output:




   +-----------+-----------+--------+---------+      
   |  cello    |  clarinet |   drums|         |      
   |           |  trumpet  |        +---------+      
   |           |   viola   |        |         |      
   +-----------+           |        |         |      
   |  violin   |           |        +---------+      
   |           +-----------+  tuba  |         |      
   |           |           |        |         |      
   |           |           |        |         |      
   |   piano   |           |        |         |      
   |           +-----------+--------+         |      
   |           |                    |         |      
   |           |  flute             |         |      
   |           |     saxaphone      |         |      
   +-----------+--------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 584 bytes:

```py
E=enumerate
U=lambda b,x,y:0<=x<len(b)and 0<=y<len(b[0])
def f(b):
 q=[(x,y,'','',0,1)for x,r in E(b)for y,l in E(r)if'['==l]
 while q:
  x,y,w,l,X,Y=q.pop(0)
  if(u:=b[x][y]).isalpha():w+=u
  if u=='/':X,Y=[-X,-Y][::-1]
  if u=='\\':X,Y=[X,Y][::-1]
  if u in'><':
   for i,a in E([w,w[::-1]][u=='<']):b[x][y+Y*i]=a
   continue
  q+=[(x+X,y+Y,w,u,X,Y)]
  b[x][y]=' '
  if'-'==u and U(b,x+1,y)and U(b,x-1,y)and' 'not in(Q:={b[x-1][y],b[x+1][y]})and{'|','+'}&Q:b[x][y]='|'
  if'|'==u and U(b,x,y-1)and U(b,x,y+1)and' 'not in(Q:={b[x][y+1],b[x][y-1]})and{'-','+'}&Q:b[x][y]='-'
 return b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVfdb9s2EH@u/goiD5M0SVHctMVgWHlI0T0WKLYOCShhoGPa4aqICiXNccr@7dlRor5pN6MN@0739bvjkRTzQ3nPs8vfcvHy8imiWfVABSmp9TVKycN6Q9Daf/IPy4tV9LRKaeasXZJtELCHhsUXiWtt6BZtQbS00GOEHTDwbVt9L/yFu@UCPfkCsQx9Ah3FHvy0YYXLtja2oyhNLLS/ZylFj@AEKQ97P/Vv/Nvo8TznuXPhwmO2dapltMZPCT4k7jkrSJrfE8dd7r2oquWoiiI7tJfKEAc3fnCb4OUyWCS9NI61GH7GQsBkX61sBQApmMwnDUy89/eNZoKVi5WduMsGhnf7K0siokzueFayrKJAP3qqDN6ND3JIpFKJuCqMxh7ZyK6D2gEkXyFV068OlNpb@Ae34wLNgXbGS8DifFlG38EHIAEvPlBeTf1QWt9tCUX37B@/fFl2caSOI8dx/EOwcAectzDGUQku6jhAQVAdJ5jHCSCOoGUlMrR@KRYoQmdnZ5YXNKP9DzxLor@oWBdIos@8ygqEpFEL/ymqu28JMFdIDQmGlJSKQtckg0/9qBkSfSSi0TL4UkCKtxNEI50GF9LIlL8W3MCj0QJ1CHoSwLMCEZSBi0TDH6eAhmmgQSKjZE4Gr5O61Ekp3WOaCFktQFN6WvxT624@YjnKGsThwDYIO/EKdJVYomNpy1asXMSz5LUY4Mj6O4FWi@M6pv4fjRA1NXrX18gzZTgy8qwGA0@5UC2Kfud8o@v0EUpWCkbrlv0/3gTdNKnl7PmZNOQfe1Y@U5GqJQjewrbN61pezZuqbgZVK/yNpDQJgbyHlbrhOwXzWpBnlg7V2hkwjXigxgXJdhTcHmia8n0Sq6neCUoziNGqzTOV80xjQ6QQTUYzJe/1lITBqwd0kkSvHrLW9uZuDFPlaW2JtoLvJm5mpOy1uYDCjbQ3rb1q@B2cZUPtKtuQkvGs12Yp29GsrLULOvCNrwUv76lI2lVR@95nre90O0IyQykx3e0aY4kBZ5k06yEeNlev3bMDElmTBox133Rs56zVHtdbzreSme9rfujdXZlKP9Ku0vTYfBu0Bd8XVLxC2zvZed4Af9O@Hwa7bjfC1/ax3lFNTXbCXb3rjheMNAaYLjmp9mh5KmBo2h5qOzRZRuNV77UI@l3B6yzHvVZvSHcpESyjqt9jfaYjvBHVQ5E0h4bspw//y3hKkhiGqWWHoLyJ6bw/R4Z99jJsj6tpE3hNfJbV22FniO/UHpnoGs8irsbTcAwqkrOlNY49daYPXNOaNNJA4LJaE13VI4Y4ZyTjSWwuzeD3aI7hz0xPpjndFsZBT6faP8Ql9E9O6w2ugaT7Z5tWJU3GPWBy1lPmgAV5IjlckOgxQ@v4y5PpoWc6ENX1qeR/rzkRG6eAW9Qb/SaNMVwumquIuohsWVpS4XwGOD4qzos8ZaVjx5ntwt2i9lJwyBsOmfou9qY3dDr3a1dJ3uSwFMHWPv@Hw9s@c13L6myLhTtg3g6ZyyHzbsi8HzIf3Jf/AA)